# How to extract column name having common values in R

Tags: r

I have dataframe i want to find common column name with corresponding value

```
 structure(list(s100.Probeset = structure(c(1L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 5L
 ), .Label = c("202055_at", "203063_at", "206284_x_at", "210734_x_at", 
 "221915_s_at"), class = "factor"), s101.Probeset = structure(c(2L, 
 4L, 3L, 1L, 5L), .Label = c("202055_at", "203248_at ", "206284_x_at", 
 "210734_x_at", "212522_at"), class = "factor"), s102.Probeset = structure(c(1L, 
 3L, 4L, 5L, 2L), .Label = c("202055_at", "205453_at", "210734_x_at", 
"219957_at", "220661_s_at"), class = "factor"), s10.Probeset =  structure(c(5L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("202055_at", "203063_at", "211503_s_at", 
"214689_at", "219957_at"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("s100.Probeset", 
"s101.Probeset", "s102.Probeset", "s10.Probeset"), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Output

> 202055_at s100.Probeset,s101.Probeset,s102.Probeset,s103.Probeset,s10.Probeset
>
> 219957_at s102.Probeset,s103.Probeset,s10.Probeset
>
> 203063_at s100.Probeset,s10.Probeset

Comment: Why is 210734 not in the 'Output'.  It is found in 3 columns.

Comment: 202055_at is common in 5 columns and that 5 column names are  s100.Probeset, s101.Probeset,s102.Probeset,s103.Probeset,s10.Probeset

Comment: You showed only 4 columns in the example.  Please check ur example

Comment: Its is there  but i have given as example output

Comment: @akrun edited my post

Comment: There is no s103 column in the example.  Anyway, I showed a way in the below solution

Answer (score 0):

We can get `unique` elements from the dataset

```
un1 <- as.character(unique(unlist(df1)))
```

Check whether if it is found in more than 1 column, then `paste`

```
out <- unlist(lapply(un1, function(x)  {
        x1 <- colSums(df1 == x)
    if(sum(x1) > 1)  paste(x, paste(names(x1)[x1>0], collapse="."))}))
out[1:2]
#[1] "202055_at s100.Probeset.s101.Probeset.s102.Probeset.s10.Probeset" 
#[2] "203063_at s100.Probeset.s10.Probeset"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to extend @akrun's answer.

I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but the binary matrix that denotes which probeset was present in which column might be useful for further processing as well.

```
# Your sample data
probes <- structure(list(s100.Probeset = structure(c(1L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 5L
 ), .Label = c("202055_at", "203063_at", "206284_x_at", "210734_x_at",
 "221915_s_at"), class = "factor"), s101.Probeset = structure(c(2L,
 4L, 3L, 1L, 5L), .Label = c("202055_at", "203248_at ", "206284_x_at",
 "210734_x_at", "212522_at"), class = "factor"), s102.Probeset = structure(c(1L,
 3L, 4L, 5L, 2L), .Label = c("202055_at", "205453_at", "210734_x_at",
"219957_at", "220661_s_at"), class = "factor"), s10.Probeset =  structure(c(5L,
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("202055_at", "203063_at", "211503_s_at",
"214689_at", "219957_at"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("s100.Probeset",
"s101.Probeset", "s102.Probeset", "s10.Probeset"), row.names = c(NA,
-5L), class = "data.frame")

# Unique probesets
unique.probes <- unique(unlist(probes));

# Binary matrix
df1 <- data.frame(
    apply(probes, 2, function(x) unique.probes %in% x),
    row.names = unique.probes);
df1;
#            s100.Probeset s101.Probeset s102.Probeset s10.Probeset
#202055_at            TRUE          TRUE          TRUE         TRUE
#203063_at            TRUE         FALSE         FALSE         TRUE
#210734_x_at          TRUE          TRUE          TRUE        FALSE
#206284_x_at          TRUE          TRUE         FALSE        FALSE
#221915_s_at          TRUE         FALSE         FALSE        FALSE
#203248_at           FALSE          TRUE         FALSE        FALSE
#212522_at           FALSE          TRUE         FALSE        FALSE
#219957_at           FALSE         FALSE          TRUE         TRUE
#220661_s_at         FALSE         FALSE          TRUE        FALSE
#205453_at           FALSE         FALSE          TRUE        FALSE
#211503_s_at         FALSE         FALSE         FALSE         TRUE
#214689_at           FALSE         FALSE         FALSE         TRUE
```

You can then close the circle to @akrun's solution.

```
# IDs per probeset
df2 <- cbind.data.frame(
    probeset = rownames(df1),
    ID = sapply(1:nrow(df1), function(x)
        paste(colnames(df1)[which(df1[x, ] == 1)], collapse = ",")));
df2;
#      probeset                                                   ID
#1    202055_at s100.Probeset,s101.Probeset,s102.Probeset,s10.Probeset
#2    203063_at                             s100.Probeset,s10.Probeset
#3  210734_x_at              s100.Probeset,s101.Probeset,s102.Probeset
#4  206284_x_at                            s100.Probeset,s101.Probeset
#5  221915_s_at                                          s100.Probeset
#6   203248_at                                           s101.Probeset
#7    212522_at                                          s101.Probeset
#8    219957_at                             s102.Probeset,s10.Probeset
#9  220661_s_at                                          s102.Probeset
#10   205453_at                                          s102.Probeset
#11 211503_s_at                                           s10.Probeset
#12   214689_at                                           s10.Probeset
```

Comment: Error in data.frame(apply(file5, 2, function(x) unique.probes %in% x),  : 
  duplicate row.names: 208996_s_at, 221105_at, 219317_at, 209530_at, 216955_at, 210657_s_at, 218198_at, 217156_at, 210335_at, 215055_at, 209099_x_at

Comment: @RKG As akrun asked you before: Please update your example to be representative. I strongly suggest revising your original post and provide a **minimal, reproducible and representative example**. Both solutions work **with the sample data that you provide**. Everything else is a guessing game, and you will find that people loose interest to help very quickly in such cases.

Comment: @Mauritis my data is very huge some 200 column with 20K rows